# How can I retain a specific RegExp in several lines using sed command?

Tags: linux, text-processing

I need to retain a specific RegExp in several lines using command `sed`.

example:

Input:

```
ARCH_17|gi|299883390|ref|NC_014300.1| Halalkalicoccus jeotgali B3 plasmid 3, complete sequence
```

Output:

```
gi|299883390
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far. We'll help you, but we won't write the whole script instead of you.

Comment: If all the lines have the showen format, you may try `awk`. Set field separator to `|` and print second and third field. If the format varies, please show us more lines and indicate, what is the common property you try to describe with reg-exp.

Comment: with the amount of information you gave, this would be a correct answer:  `sed 's/^.*$/gi|299883390/'` (which is nonsense). If you always want the same fields, no regex needed, use `cut` or `awk`, e.g. `cut -d'|' -f2,3`

Answer (score 0):

I was trying through trial and error and the following command worked for my purpose

```
sed 's/\(^>.*\|\)\(gi.*\)\(|ref.*\)/>\2/g' myfile
```

However, as you mention, awk and cut commands are way more simple and practical in the context.